# Why doesn't it feel suffocating when taking a shower?

Tags: human-biology, breathing

When one walks into a bathroom where someone is (or just finished) taking a shower it is hard to breathe, because it's filled with steam, yet the person taking a shower can breathe just fine despite being in the area with even more steam.

Why is that?

Comment: Can you support that this is a general perception? I've never felt suffocated when entering a steam-filled shower.

Comment: @fileunderwater: Nor have I, in an actual steam room.  Seems like an individual idiosyncrasy.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a matter of relative perception.

For example, if you start with empty hands and pick up a 20 pound weight, you will perceive it as heavier than if you start with a 10 pound weight and then pick up a 20 pound weight.

Likewise, whoever's in the shower had plenty of time to get accustomed to gradually increasing steam, while you walked in and got the full blast immediately.